# WordPress deployment when database is full of string length parameters

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Some plugins and themes use in database json (?) where is used "s" parameter. Maybe example will be good here:

```
(9238, 14133, '_mail', 'a:9:{s:6:"active";b:1;s:7:"subject";s:25:"Website title";s:6:"sender";s:49:"[your-name] <wordpress@domain.com>";s:9:"recipient";s:46:"mail1@domain.com";s:4:"body";s:210:"Nadawca: [your-name] <[your-email]>\n\nTreść wiadomości:\n[your-message]\n\n-- \nTa wiadomość została wysłana przez formularz kontaktowy na stronie";s:18:"additional_headers";s:22:"Reply-To: [your-email]";s:11:"attachments";s:0:"";s:8:"use_html";b:0;s:13:"exclude_blank";b:0;}'),
```

As you can see every string in this row has something like "s:6". It means that following string has 6 chars. I moved from example real domains, etc. so not all lengths are correct now.

Why I'm writing about that. I usually prepare project on my my dev copy on my server and when it's done I copy that to target server (prod). I make this deployment in this standard way:

1. Copy all files from dev to prod (using ssh usually)
2. Export dev database
3. Manually change dev links to prod links in database (e.g. website.dev.domain.com to website-prod-domain.com)
4. Import database with changes to prod
5. Change database credentials in wp-config

And everything goes easy until there are in database some "s:" parameters. Then I usually have to go to WP admin panel and manually set all configuration in plugins and personalize options which are not working after deployment.

Is there any good solution or script to make my deployment easy also in case when I meet "s:" on my way?

Comment: it's not json. it's `php serialize` data. you should unserialize it, mke changes you want, serialize it back and update db

Comment: There are several suggestions for tools and scripts that can do this on the official [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) page (see under "Changing Your Domain Name and URLs".) Note that questions asking for tool recommendations are considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was about serialized data. The best way I found is using plugin dedicated to migrate database: https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/
The plugin works very nice with serialized data (Find & replace that handles serialized data).